Trying to implement Comparable in a class using a Type from a superclass
i want to  implement the Comparable interface and override compareTo. All of that seems to work fine, but i am really confused by my testing results.If i try to call compareTo with 2 Rationals, i get the "Symbol not found" error. I looked that up already and someone suggested converting the Rationals to a String. When i do that, fsr it seems like I am not even calling my own fuction (i changed parameters within the function, which changed nothing), instead the programm always returns 2. If i compare to equals it works fine though.
This is my code, i can add the packages if needed.
`package app.exercise.testing;
import app.exercise.algebra.*;
import java.lang.Comparable;

public class compRational extends Rational implements Comparable<Rational>{


   public int compareTo(Rational y){
        System.out.println("Troubleshoot: "+(int)this.getN()*(int)y.getD()+ " "+(int)y.getN()*(int)this.getD());
        return Integer.compare((int)this.getN()*(int)y.getD(),(int)y.getN()*(int)this.getD());

    }
    //Testing

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Rational test=new Rational(3,8);
        Rational test2=new Rational(10,3);
        Rational test3=new Rational(3,8);
        // Compare

        System.out.println("Compare Test: "+test.compareTo(test2));
        if((test.toString().compareTo(test3.toString())==0) == test.equals(test3)){
            System.out.println("compare test 2: "+true);
        }


    }
}`

Since the first line of the comparable function never worked (The "Troubleshoot" print), i am assuming calling compareTo w/ two Strings does not call my own compareTo, which leaves me confused how i would even call my own function
EDIT: resolved the issue. The compRational class simply implements Comparable, but I now overwrite the compareTo() function in Rational. Thanks everyone for the help.
More detailed explanation of the fix:
Rational class - note that i overwrite compareTo in the second function without implementing it.
public class Rational extends BasisFraction{
    private long numerator;
    private long denominator;
    
    /**
    Implementierung von setND aus @see BasisFraction um Parameter eines @see Rational Objekts zu verändern
    Parameter
    @param numerator neuer Zähler des Objekts
    @pram denominator neuer Nenner des Objekts
    
    */
    
    
    /**
    @Override
    */
    public int compareTo(Rational y){
        return Integer.compare((int)this.getN()*(int)y.getD(),(int)y.getN()*(int)this.getD());

    }   
    
    
    protected void setND (long numerator, long denominator ){
        long teiler=ggT(numerator, denominator);
        this.numerator=numerator/teiler;
        this.denominator=denominator/teiler;
    }
    
    /**Default Konstruktor für @see Rational
    */
    public Rational(){
        setND(1,1);
    }
    
    /**
    Konstruktor für @see Rational
    kürzt mit @see ggT weitmöglichst, setzt nur Zähler negativ falls notwendig
    Parameter
    @param n Nenner
    @param d Zähler
    */
    public Rational(long n,long d){
        long teiler=ggT(n,d);
        n=n/teiler;
        d=d/teiler;
        if(d < 0){
            setND(-n,-d);
        }
        else{
        setND(n, d);
        }
    }
    
    /**
    Kehrwert
    @return Kehrwert übergebender rationaler Zahl
    */
    public Fractional reciprocal(){
        Rational rückgabe= new Rational(this.denominator, this.numerator);  
        return rückgabe;
    }
    
    /**
    * *(-1)
    @return übergebende rationale Zahl *(-1)
    */
    public Fractional negation(){
        Rational rückgabe=new Rational(this.numerator*-1,this.denominator);
        return rückgabe;
    }
    
    /**
    getter Nenner
    
    @return Nenner
    */
    public long getD(){
        return this.denominator;
    }
    
    /**
    getter Zähler
    
    @return Zähler
    */
    public long getN(){
        return this.numerator;
    }
    
    /**größter gemeinsamer Teiler
    @param n Zahl 1
    @param d Zahl 2
    */
    public static long ggT(long n, long d){
        if(d == 0)
                    return n;
            return ggT(d, n%d);
    }
    
    /**
    Umwandlung eines @see Rational Objekts in einen Strin
    Rückgabe
    @return Zähler / Nenner
    */
    public String toString(){
        return "" +getN() + "/"+getD();
        
    }
    
    /**
    Kopiert übergebendes Objekt
    Rückgabe
    @return neues Objekt mit gleichen Parametern
    */
    public Rational clone(){
        Rational rückgabe=new Rational(this.getN(), this.getD());
        return rückgabe;
    }
    
    /**
    überprüft ob 2 Objekte gleich sind, also dieselben Parameter enthalten
    Parameter
    @param y @Rational Objekt mit dem verglichen wird
    @return bool
    */
    public boolean equals(Rational y){
        if(this.getN()==y.getN()&&this.getD()==y.getD()){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    /**
    berechnet Hashcode eines Objekts, indem Zähler+Nenner quadriert und mod 10 gerechnet wird
    @return HashCode
    */
    public int hashCode(){
        return (int)Math.pow(this.getN()+this.getD(),2)%10;
    }
}

Now the final compRational class with Testfeatures: Since compRational extends Rational it inherits the compareTo method declared in the Rational class, which overwrites compareTo from Comparable.
package app.exercise.algebra;
import java.lang.Comparable;

public class compRational extends Rational implements Comparable<Rational>{
 public static void main(String args[]){
        Rational test=new Rational(3,8);
        Rational test2=new Rational(10,3);
        Rational test3=new Rational(3,8);
        // Compare

        System.out.println("Compare Test: "+test.compareTo(test2));
        if((test.compareTo(test3)==0) == test.equals(test3)){
            System.out.println("compare test 2: "+true);
        }

    }
}


You need to implement Comparable in your Rational class. Either that, or create instances of your CompRational class to compare.

I was specifically asked to implement it in CompRational though

See the second half of my comment.

My bad didnt catch that. So you're saying i have to create compRational Objects instead of Rational Objects? Because tbh that also somewhat defeats the purpose as 2 Rational Objects should be compared

Yeah, I didn't come up with those requirements :) The regular approach is to make the base class implement Comparable, or to create an external Comparator.

the external Comparator being creating instances of CompRational?yeah i know thank you for your help already.

Nope, the external Comparator being an instance of Comparator.

Unrelated but always a good idea to put the @Override annotation before any overridden method.   It can save some debugging time if you accidentally specify the wrong method signature.

OK.  Without knowing more details about what is exactly expected of your task, you're going to need to:

implement Comparable<Rational>
include a new constructor to instantiate the class with the arguments.

public CompRational(int num, int den) {
    super(num,den);
}


implement the Comparable interface

@Override
public int compareTo(Rational y) {
   // your existing code here
}


then create the instances

CompRational test = new CompRational(3, 8);
CompRational test2 = new CompRational(10, 3);
CompRational test3 = new CompRational(3, 8);

Note: Classes should start with upper case letters

Thanks for the answer, I already resolved the issue (see edit in OP). I thought I had to overwrite compareTo in compRational, which isnt the case, I am only supposed to implement it there. Thanks again though, would have used that otherwise.

@LeonPreuße  "but I now overwrite the compareTo() function in Rational."  So are you saying Rational implements Comparable<Rational>?  How are you creating instances of Rational to compare? Showing the Rational class would have been useful as it is still not clear what changes you made.

Alright i added Rational. I pretty much put compareTo in Rational. Since compRational extends Rational, it also uses compareTo as declared in Rational. Which overwrites compareTo from Comparable.
-> Comparable is implemented in compRational but compareTo  isdeclared in Rational and inherited by compRational

@LeonPreuße. Makes sense.  Didn't realize that you could modify the Rational class.  Thanks for the clarification.
